# 2d array multiple movement selection sort

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array, bubble-sort

I am trying to write a method that sorts (using bubble sort) the items in every other row of a 2d array. When a movement happens in the first row, I want the category number in the row immediately under the row being sorted to also move. The bubble sort works correctly for the first half of the array, but then stops half way through the array and the movement for the row underneath does not happen correctly.

```
for(int i = 0; i<differencearray.length; i= i+2){ //skips every other row
        for(int j = 0; j<differencearray[i].length; j++){
            for(int l = 0; l<differencearray[i].length-1; l++){
                if(differencearray[j][l]>differencearray[j][l+1]){
                    int temp = differencearray[j][l]; //moves row being sorted
                    differencearray[j][l] = differencearray[j][l+1];
                    differencearray[j][l+1] = temp;
                    int temp1 = differencearray[i+1][j]; //moves row immediately below what is being sorted
                    differencearray[i+1][j] = differencearray[i+1][l];
                    differencearray[i+1][l] = temp1;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Expected output:

9 13 15 24 2147483647

3 4 2 5 1

15 16 17 18 2147483647

1 4 5 3 2

9 12 18 27 2147483647

1 4 2 5 3

12 13 16 25 2147483647

3 1 2 5 4

17 24 25 27 2147483647

2 1 4 3 5

Actual output:

9 13 15 24 2147483647

1 2 3 4 5

15 16 17 18 2147483647

1 2 3 4 5

9 12 18 27 2147483647

1 4 3 2 5

13 16 12 2147483647 25

1 4 2 3 5

24 17 27 25 2147483647

2 4 3 1 5

Any idea of what I am doing wrong? Thank you in advance!

Comment: I think you'd better add some test input that you've used to the above code.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this to be helpful.

```
import java.util.Arrays;


public class BloodySort {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] differencearray = {
                {9, 13, 15, 2},
                {1, 2, 3, 4},
                {9, 13, 15, 2, 17, 29, 31, 88, 56, 5, 4},
                {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11}
        };

        for(int i = 0; i<differencearray.length; i= i+2){ //skips every other row
            for(int j = 0; j<differencearray[i].length-1; j++){
                for(int l = j+1; l<differencearray[i].length; l++){
                    if(differencearray[i][j]>differencearray[i][l]){
                        int temp = differencearray[i][j]; //moves row being sorted
                        differencearray[i][j] = differencearray[i][l];
                        differencearray[i][l] = temp;

                        int temp1 = differencearray[i+1][j]; //moves row immediately below what is being sorted
                        differencearray[i+1][j] = differencearray[i+1][l];
                        differencearray[i+1][l] = temp1;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        for ( int i = 0; i < differencearray.length; ++i ) {
            System.out.println( Arrays.toString(differencearray[i]) );
        }
    }
}
```

And it gave the following (correct, I think) answer.

```
[2, 9, 13, 15]
[4, 1, 2, 3]
[2, 4, 5, 9, 13, 15, 17, 29, 31, 56, 88]
[4, 11, 10, 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 9, 8]
```

Comment: Thank you for your assistance, but this still does not resolve the problem. Using your code, the print out is much nicer, but the array still only sorts for half of the rows, and the movement of the category rows does not match the movement of the sorting of the rows being sorted. Any ideas for those problems? Thanks again!

Comment: Could you provide some of the test input?